# How print column data given conditions? CSV Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm new to programming. Is there a way for Ruby to select the conditions for column 1 and 2, while I print columns 0 and 3 (In the context of the same row)

Take for example I would like to print out the "description" and "equipment" when there is an event type of "high" and severity "1".

[image]

I could not print out my equipment and description

```
require "csv"
equipment = []
description = []
def find_severity(event_type, severity)
    alarms = CSV.read 'alarms.csv', {col_sep: ';'}
    result = alarms.select do |level|
          level[1] == event_type && level[2].to_i == severity.to_i
          equipment[] = level[0]
          description[] = level[3]
    end
end

p find_severity('high', 1)
p equipment
p description
```

Comment: "equipment[] = level[10]" - no, this is not php. Here it's done differently: `equipment.push(level[10])`. And these should be outside the `select`, I think.

Comment: Also, `level[10]` and `level[13]`? What did you mean by that? You only have 4 columns.

Comment: Ah, sorry I changed the values.

Comment: The issue is that I would like to check if the event type is 'high' and severity is '1' before printing out 'DT24/SIG  Repair doors' and '90430/RSO' 'Repair lift'

Comment: yep, select first, print later.

Comment: If you would write `equipment << level[0]` you would already correctly collect the equipments. But @keithbennett 's answer is better: first "select" the rows and then decide how you want to show it :)

Comment: I would get "undefined local variable or method 'equipment', I would like to the logic of my code and will try Keith's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest breaking down the tasks into methods for their respective responsibilities. You have here loading, filtering, and transforming. The methods could reflect that. (I haven't tested this code, but this should show the general idea.)

I think you'd be better off with something like this:

```
require "csv"

def load_alarms
  CSV.read 'alarms.csv', {col_sep: ';'}
end

def filter_by_event_type_and_severity(alarms, event_type, severity)
  alarms.select do |alarm|
    alarm[1] == event_type && alarm[2].to_i == severity.to_i
  end
end

target_alarms = filter_by_event_type_and_severity(
    load_alarms, 'high', 1)
equipments   = target_alarms.map { |alarm| alarm[0] }
descriptions = target_alarms.map { |alarm| alarm[3] }

p target_alarms
p equipments
p descriptions
```

Even if the implementations of the methods are trivially simple, this will give you the practice of separating code into logical parts, each of which is highly cohesive or specialized, with minimal coupling (dependency) on other parts of the code.

One of the biggest mistakes of beginners is trying to do too much in the same chunk of code -- high and low level code, and with totally unrelated subjects. Learning how to break problems down into smaller problems, and logically organizing them, is one of the important skills you can learn.

By the way, I don't recommend the `to_i` call on `severity`. Since the parameter is logically a number, you shouldn't really permit a string, IMO.

Comment: Hi for the code 'def filter_by_event_type_and_severity(alarms, event_type, severity)' I get an error "wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3") would you know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're only passing 2 arguments. I added the first argument, the array of records, to what you had. So maybe that's the one that's missing? You can post code to show us; one site for that is gist.github.com.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kaeltharlas/cdeddca2d0d71dbeea40ffa160fbb27b Here's the code. It's the same as yours, could you try to run it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the code in my answer, and didn't think you would have copied it so fast so I didn't mention it. Try copying the last 3 lines of the code currently in the answer and replacing the corresponding 3 last lines of your code.

Comment: It works now, thank you very much!! I've tried to edit your code to have the equipment and description on the same array. (\n will be the next row of equipment and description) But I've gotten other results. Could you enlighten me on this?

Comment: One way to create the display line would be to use printf-style formatting to put the entries in aligned columns, like this: `eq_and_desc_lines = target_alarms.map { |alarm| "%-15.15s%s" % [alarm[0], alarm[3]] }`. You might need to adjust the width setting for proper alignment.

Comment: If I would like to send it as an sms, all I need is to have it stored in an array am I right?

Comment: I have no idea. What does the SMS interface require? It's probably a single string, and it may not accommodate the size that you need. If it were possible to send an attachment, perhaps you could send it as a text file, but I don't think that's possible with SMS -- maybe MMS?

Comment: Hmm I’ll work on it on the weekends and will post something up next week. Thank you very much for your help though! I really appreciate it

Comment: Hi Keith, I was wondering how would you combine equipments and descriptions to one single array?

Comment: What would you want each element of the array to look like?

Comment: I'm not sure if array is the correct term.. After filtering the event type and severity, I would need the output to be ["Equipment", "Description"] .

Comment: `target_alarms.map { |alarm| [alarm[0], alarm[3]] }`

Comment: Would there be another command to split up my iteration? 
That is to say, I would like the rows to be seperated and printf seperately

Comment: If you mean one on each line, `puts` will do that for arrays.

Comment: Ah I see. As I picture my program to be reading data real-time. Currently, this code would send a bunch a code at one go. I was wondering it’s possible to send a row at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you mean have a stream of records constantly being analyzed, then one way to do it is to write to a log file as the events are occurring, and calling `tail -f` on the file to display the most recent lines in a terminal window.

Comment: Hi Keith, I have posted another question to state the issue in a more concise format. Thank you for your inputs on this question, I hope you could check out the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858646/twilio-sms-using-ruby