# Twilio SMS using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, twilio

I've been working on a program that would read a CSV excel file and filter the information to be sent via sms. Currently, the program is only able to send one row of filtered information via sms. What should be modified to be able to send row after row seperately?

Currently the code searches for 'medium' and '2' on columns 1 and 2. It would send out columns 0 and 4. Hence the results would be "DT3/SIG, "Repair Windows"
but it wouldnt send out row 5 - "90430/RSO", "Repair Lights"

[image]

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'
require "csv"

def load_alarms
  CSV.read 'alarms.csv', {col_sep: ';'}
end

def filter_by_event_type_and_severity(alarms, event_type, severity)
  alarms.select do |alarm|
    alarm[1] == event_type && alarm[2].to_i == severity.to_i
  end
end

target_alarms = filter_by_event_type_and_severity(
    load_alarms, 'medium', 2)
equipments  = target_alarms.map { |alarm| [alarm[0], alarm[3]] }

p equipments

account_sid = 'ACCOUNT_ID'
auth_token = 'AUTH_TOKEN'
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

client.api.account.messages.create(
    from: 'SENDER_PHONE',
    to: 'TARGET_PHONE',
    body: equipments
  )
```

Comment: you should iterate over `equipments` and send each with `client.api.account.messages.create`... something like: `equipments.each do |equipment| ...client.api.account.messages.create... end`

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually very new to programming and I'm not sure how you would frame that up, could you write a sample code? Thanks

Comment: ok, will do it in a few mins :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i wrote in the comment, all you need to do is iterate over the `equipments` you got from the `filter_by_event_type_and_severity` method, and send them one by one with the `twillo` api:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'
require "csv"

def load_alarms
  CSV.read 'alarms.csv', {col_sep: ';'}
end

def filter_by_event_type_and_severity(alarms, event_type, severity)
  alarms.select do |alarm|
    alarm[1] == event_type && alarm[2].to_i == severity.to_i
  end
end

target_alarms = filter_by_event_type_and_severity(load_alarms, 'medium', 2)
equipments  = target_alarms.map { |alarm| [alarm[0], alarm[3]] }

account_sid = 'ACCOUNT_ID'
auth_token = 'AUTH_TOKEN'
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

# Here is the iteration
equipments.each do |equipment|
  client.api.account.messages.create(
    from: 'SENDER_PHONE',
    to: 'TARGET_PHONE',
    body: equipment
  )
end
```

**I removed your account_id, auth_token and phone numbers, so you need to add them back**

Comment: Ah sorry, I realized it only sends column 0 but it does not send out column 3. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Right now, the body is including the `equipment` object, which is an array of 2 things, the equipment id and the equipment description. You'd probably want to format a string containing that information in your desired format. What do you want that string to look like? You could add `id, description = equipment` after the `equipments.each` line and then build a string with them as you like, and send that string as the body. For example, `"#{id} - #{description}"` as the body.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I've added the line 'p equipment' and it prints the equipment id and description. ["id", "Description"]. The body was suppose to send the same information but I've only received "id".

Comment: @JoshuaNg If it shows it as `["id", "Description"]` then you might try `"#{equipment[0]} - #{equipment[1]}" - if it acts as an array. (@KeithBennett's method didn't work?)

Comment: my id and description is already part of `equipments`. They are `[alarm[10], alarm[13]]` But  `body: equipment` does not send both, I only receive `[alarm[10]`

Comment: this is the time for trial and error! :D (if i had your csv file i could try it myself) but try `body: "#{equipment[0]} - #{equipment[1]}"` (this comment section is getting long, if u need more help join [**THIS CHAT ROOM**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165443/twilio-sms-using-ruby) that i created to help you ^^)